# Why is @Sql ignored in my Spring integration tests?

Tags: spring, spring-test

For Spring Framework 6 - ***for academic purposes***, the `@Repository` works directly with a `DataSource`. Therefore there is **no** neither a `JdbcTemplate` nor `DataSourceTransactionManager` involved. The `@Repository` has many CRUD methods implemented. They work as expected and there is a Test class to test a sequence of crud events, such as: insertion, find, count, update, find, count, etc ... it such as:

```java
    @SpringJUnitConfig(classes={AppConfig.class})
    @DisplayName("Testing All CRUD Test Methods according with a specific order")
    @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
    class CientificoServiceCrudTests {
    
        @Autowired
        private CientificoService cientificoService;

    ...
```

and all pass.

But when `@SQL` is involved as follows:

```java
    @Sql(scripts={"classpath:com/manuel/jordan/mysql/v1/schema.sql",
                  "classpath:com/manuel/jordan/mysql/v1/data.sql"})
    @SpringJUnitConfig(classes={AppConfig.class})
    @DisplayName("Testing All CRUD Test Methods according with a specific order")
    @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
    class CientificoServiceCrudTests {
    
       ...
    
       @Test
       @Order(3)
       @Sql(scripts={"classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/mysql/v1/insert.sql"})
       @DisplayName("Testing 'save' with 'id' 14")
       void saveWithId14Test() {
         ...
```

Was confirmed the `@Sql` scripts are **not** executed because they are **ignored**.

They were **not** executed because the tests methods fail due the assertions and they were **ignored** because as a simple experiment if is established invalid paths for the script files, for example:

> @Sql(scripts={"classpath:/**xxx**com/manuel/jordan/mysql/v1/insert.sql"})

The tests methods fail *as indicated before* due the assertions **but** *from the beginning* **never** was reported  that the script file was not found because it does not exist - it as could be expected.

**Question**

- Can @Sql work directly with DataSource and without transactions?

If not, is it an expected behavior? Or Does the test class need something extra?

**Note** The app uses a unique `DataSource` which works with `MySQL`

Comment: Do you have `spring-tx` on the classpath?

Comment: @SamBrannen - There is no `spring-jdbc` nor `spring-tx` in the path - due academics purposes, is shown how Spring works with _plain_ `jdbc`. But I was wondered why was not thrown none Exception due the invalid paths ... Later is going to be integrated `JdbcTemplate` and `DataSourceTransactionManager`

Comment: Because [Sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.java) is declared in the `spring-test` module I thought was enough use that dependency - and **yes** - you are correct - was enough add the `spring-txt` module in the path to see the expected error and get working the `Sql` annotation. Now because you are the author of that annotation: What class is involved in the `spring-txt` module that _"uses and manages"_ the `Sql` annotation? - is it documented in some place? As usual - Thanks for your guidance

Comment: BTW was mandatory add the `spring-jdbc` module, otherwise arise `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils`

Comment: It may well be the case that the dependency on `spring-jdbc` and `spring-tx` is not documented. Feel free to open an issue to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@Sql` annotations are ignored because the `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener` is not active... because `spring-tx` and `spring-jdbc` are not on the classpath.

Those are required: If you look at the source code for `SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`, you can see in the imports that the listener uses `ResourceDatabasePopulator` from `spring-jdbc` and various types from `spring-tx`.

However, no exception is propagated to the user if one of those dependencies is missing, because it's not necessarily an *error*.

Rationale: the *Spring TestContext Framework* attempts to register all *default* `TestExecutionListener`s. If one of the listeners cannot be loaded -- for example, due to a missing dependency in the classpath -- Spring will log that at `DEBUG` level.

This is by design: to support "optional" listeners. Effectively, almost all listeners are optional. This applies to listeners provided by `spring-test` as well as those provided by Spring portfolio projects (Boot, Security, etc.) and any third-party libraries.